# json data not displaying on the leaflet map

Tags: json, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I can get the php response using

```
$("#resultTable").html(response)
```

which results in json as below:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    "[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\": \"Point\",\"coordinates\":[144.88492596994729,-37.630939830943923]},\"properties\":{\"id\":6.680000000000000e+002,\"eno\":\"E1421\",\"start_yr\":2.023000000000000e+003,\"sch_sex\":\"CO-ED\",\"psx\":\"P\",\"sch_level\":\"Primary\"}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\": \"Point\",\"coordinates\":[145.33476983598635,-38.138394865105511]},\"properties\":{\"id\":6.720000000000000e+002,\"eno\":\"E4049\",\"start_yr\":2.025000000000000e+003,\"sch_sex\":\"CO-ED\",\"psx\":\"P\",\"sch_level\":\"Primary\"}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\": \"Point\",\"coordinates\":[145.36314683445636,-38.107667866900812]},\"properties\":{\"id\":6.710000000000000e+002,\"eno\":\"E4048\",\"start_yr\":2.024000000000000e+003,\"sch_sex\":\"CO-ED\",\"psx\":\"P\",\"sch_level\":\"Primary\"}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\": \"Point\",\"coordinates\":[144.6851299838919,-37.8237898186311]},\"properties\":{\"id\":6.600000000000000e+002,\"eno\":\"E1416\",\"start_yr\":2.024000000000000e+003,\"sch_sex\":\"CO-ED\",\"psx\":\"P\",\"sch_level\":\"Primary\"}}]"
  ]
}
```

To check if this is a valid json, I saved above texts (strings) as a geojson file and checked its validity in https://jsonformatter.org/ It returns as valid json.
It seems all good. But, when I convert the *response* output into json object to display on the leaflet map, it throws error *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 2362*.
Part of the code to display geojson in the map is as below:

```
       var queryLayer=L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response)).addTo(mymap);
```

I am expecting json feature to display on the map.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `features` is strangely an array of strings, instead of being an array of GeoJSON Features. So it is valid JSON, but invalid GeoJSON. You can use lint tools specialized for GeoJSON, e.g. https://geojsonlint.com/

That string seems to represent the array of Features that should be directly there.

If your sample is the result after a first `JSON.parse`, then you could do:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(response); // 1st parse
data.features = JSON.parse(data.features[0]); // 2nd parse to convert the string into a proper JS array

// Then you can use the GeoJSON object
L.geoJSON(data);
```

Comment: The sample is not the result of first JSON.parse(). It is a response from php (data extract from sql server using json path).I used below code to see how output looks like: 'success: function(response){$("#resultTable").html(response);}'

Comment: `success: function(response){$("#resultTable").html(response);}`

Comment: What exactly do you get if you `console.log(response)` instead?

Comment: I get the same json string

Comment: If `response` is directly a string, then the above answer should work.

Comment: you said   _Your features is strangely an array of strings, instead of being an array of GeoJSON Features_. I am trying to learn geojson. Can you please point me where in the above Geojosn the issue is? If I can output correct geojson i believe we can fix the issue.

Comment: i think i found the issue: it contains extra double quotes and square bracket thus making it array of strings `"[.........]"` in above geojson. I managed to get rid of extra [ ] but not able to get rid of extra double quotes in geojson.

Comment: Have you tried the above answer?

Comment: I tried it did not work. But, I managed to find the core issue and solution. Above, I use json path in SQL to retrieve record as Json from sql server. Then I create an array to include feature collection and add output from sql server as feature array. While doing that it added the sql server output as a string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards https://geojsonlint.com/. It actually pin-pointed where the issue was. so some change in code to create and read the output made it work.